# SwiftUI List Children - Cast Empty Array to Optional Array

Tags: swiftui

We're using Hierarchical lists in SwiftUI. The List takes an optional array for the children argument `children: \.children`. We would like to however use a 'non-optional' array

Example from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list

```
struct ContentView: View {
    struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
        var id: Self { self }
        var name: String
        var children: [FileItem]? = nil
        var description: String {
            switch children {
            case nil:
                return " \(name)"
            case .some(let children):
                return children.isEmpty ? " \(name)" : " \(name)"
            }
        }
    }
    let fileHierarchyData: [FileItem] = [
      FileItem(name: "users", children:
        [FileItem(name: "user1234", children:
          [FileItem(name: "Photos", children:
            [FileItem(name: "photo001.jpg"),
             FileItem(name: "photo002.jpg")]),
           FileItem(name: "Movies", children:
             [FileItem(name: "movie001.mp4")]),
              FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
          ]),
         FileItem(name: "newuser", children:
           [FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
           ])
        ]),
        FileItem(name: "private", children: nil)
    ]
    var body: some View {
        List(fileHierarchyData, children: \.children) { item in
            Text(item.description)
        }
    }
}
```

so instead of using
`var children: [FileItem]? = nil`

we'd like to use
`var children: [FileItem] = []`

This of course produces a compiler error

```
Key path value type '[FileItem]' cannot be converted to contextual type '[FileItem]?'
```

How can one cast from [FileItem] to [FileItem]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach is force-unwrapped optional (to fulfil List contract) and initial value and guard setter, so in all places it can be used directly  w/o `?`. It is the same approach as is used for `IBOutlet` declarations.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
struct ContentView: View {
    struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
        var id: Self { self }
        var name: String

        var children: [FileItem]! = [] { // with default !!
            didSet {
                if children == nil {     // guard !!
                    children = []
                }
            }
        }

        var description: String {
            children.isEmpty ? " \(name)" : " \(name)" // << direct use !!
        }
    }
    let fileHierarchyData: [FileItem] = [
      FileItem(name: "users", children:
        [FileItem(name: "user1234", children:
          [FileItem(name: "Photos", children:
            [FileItem(name: "photo001.jpg"),
             FileItem(name: "photo002.jpg")]),
           FileItem(name: "Movies", children:
             [FileItem(name: "movie001.mp4")]),
              FileItem(name: "Documents")
          ]),
         FileItem(name: "newuser", children:
           [FileItem(name: "Documents")
           ])
        ]),
        FileItem(name: "private")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List(fileHierarchyData, children: \.children) { item in
            Text(item.description)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's assume I'm pulling [FileItem] from an external package and cannot change the struct. Is it possible to cast within the List Function `List(fileHierarchyData, children: \.children)`

Comment: No, casting here is not possible, but it is possible to create local extension with own computable property, like `var subitems: [FileItem]?  { children }` and use `\.subitems` keypath instead of `.children`.

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question is you want to use non-optional array you can update like this.

```
var children: [FileItem]! = [] {
        didSet {
            if children.isEmpty {
                children = []
            }
        }
    }
```